# Cargar datos desde archivo csv muy grande para entrenamiento de red neuronal

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, keras

tengo un archivo csv con 30 millones de registros y 400 columnas. Quiero cargar batchs de datos para entrenar una red neuronal con keras (python). ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Además, tengo una ultima duda: ¿existe una manera de cargar un batch y pasarlo por un preprocesamiento (trasformaciones tipo OHC, minimax creadas desde antes)?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Respondiendo tu duda, sí. Por favor lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder ser ayudado.

Comment: Ya lo leí, no veo que tiene de malo mi pregunta.

Comment: Mi sugerencia sería que comprimas ese csv a parquet [Convert csv to parquet file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604133/convert-csv-to-parquet-file-using-python)... de ahí hay varios caminos para entrenar tu red neuronal... local o usar algún servicio en la nube como aws, gcp, azure, ...